# Crash in ForEach when deleting element with NavigationView and sheet

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode13

Using Xcode 13's new [binding variant](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:content:)-96gx9) of `ForEach` my app crashes predictably on-device (but works in the simulator) when deleting any element other than the last one from content backed by an `@Published` property.

Strangely, this only happens when the view is contained within a `NavigationView` and has a sheet attached.

Here is a self-contained app demonstrating the issue:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Vegetable: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
}

class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var vegetables: [Vegetable] = [
        Vegetable(id: UUID(), name: "Eggplant"),
        Vegetable(id: UUID(), name: "Corn"),
        Vegetable(id: UUID(), name: "Radish")
    ]
}

@main
struct SwiftUIForEachTestApp: App {
    @StateObject var model = MyModel()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(model)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // Remove the containing NavigationView and the crash disappears
        NavigationView {
            MyView()
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: MyModel
    @State private var isPresentingSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($model.vegetables) { $vegetable in
                Text(vegetable.name)
            }
            .onDelete { indices in model.vegetables.remove(atOffsets: indices) }
        }
        // Remove the sheet and the crash disappears
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingSheet) {
        }
    }
}
```

Running the app and deleting the top row results in the following crash (line 16 corresponds to `@main`):

```
#0  0x00000001a73a6eac in _swift_runtime_on_report ()
#1  0x00000001a741f100 in _swift_stdlib_reportFatalErrorInFile ()
#2  0x00000001a705e668 in closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) ()
#3  0x00000001a705dce0 in _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) ()
#4  0x00000001a703c6b4 in _ArrayBuffer._checkInoutAndNativeTypeCheckedBounds(_:wasNativeTypeChecked:) ()
#5  0x00000001a7041e2c in Array.subscript.read ()
#6  0x00000001a7041d58 in protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance [τ_0_0] ()
#7  0x0000000100320c38 in closure #1 in ForEach<>.init<τ_0_0>(_:id:content:) ()
#8  0x0000000100320f48 in partial apply for closure #1 in ForEach<>.init<τ_0_0>(_:id:content:) ()
#9  0x0000000100320fd8 in thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed τ_1_0.Collection.Index) -> (@out τ_1_0.Collection.Index, @out τ_0_1) ()
#10 0x0000000100321090 in partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed τ_1_0.Collection.Index) -> (@out τ_1_0.Collection.Index, @out τ_0_1) ()
#11 0x00000001a7193d0c in LazyMapSequence<>.subscript.read ()
#12 0x00000001a71938e4 in protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance <> LazyMapSequence<τ_0_0, τ_0_1> ()
#13 0x00000001aa2a374c in ForEach.IDGenerator.makeID(data:index:offset:) ()
#14 0x00000001aa2abf54 in ForEachState.ForEachViewIDCollection.subscript.getter ()
#15 0x00000001aa2ac914 in ForEachState.ForEachViewIDCollection.subscript.read ()
#16 0x00000001aa2ac84c in protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance ForEachState<τ_0_0, τ_0_1, τ_0_2>.ForEachViewIDCollection ()
#17 0x00000001aa37a838 in _ViewList_ID._Views.subscript.getter ()
#18 0x00000001aa37a3f4 in protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance _ViewList_ID.Views ()
#19 0x00000001a71eaecc in Slice.subscript.getter ()
#20 0x00000001a71ed008 in Slice.subscript.read ()
#21 0x00000001a71ecf48 in protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance Slice<τ_0_0> ()
#22 0x00000001a7193cc8 in LazyMapSequence<>.subscript.read ()
#23 0x00000001a71938e4 in protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance <> LazyMapSequence<τ_0_0, τ_0_1> ()
#24 0x00000001aa157f44 in ShadowRowCollection.subscript.getter ()
#25 0x00000001aa1580ec in ShadowRowCollection.subscript.read ()
#26 0x00000001aa15802c in protocol witness for Collection.subscript.read in conformance ShadowRowCollection<τ_0_0> ()
#27 0x00000001aa365448 in ListCoreDataSource.rowID(at:) ()
#28 0x00000001aa004ec0 in closure #1 in performUpdates #1 <τ_0_0, τ_0_1>() in ListCoreCoordinator.updateUITableView(_:to:transaction:) ()
#29 0x00000001a9ffd09c in specialized _ArrayProtocol.filter(_:) ()
#30 0x00000001aa004658 in performUpdates #1 <τ_0_0, τ_0_1>() in ListCoreCoordinator.updateUITableView(_:to:transaction:) ()
#31 0x00000001aa00565c in closure #1 in ListCoreCoordinator.updateUITableView(_:to:transaction:) ()
#32 0x00000001a9ec6008 in thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () ()
#33 0x00000001a9eaee84 in static Update.end() ()
#34 0x00000001a9cd7390 in static NSRunLoop.flushObservers() ()
#35 0x00000001a9cd72d8 in closure #1 in closure #1 in static NSRunLoop.addObserver(_:) ()
#36 0x00000001a9cd2250 in specialized thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> (@error @owned Error) ()
#37 0x00000001c9b53f24 in autoreleasepool<τ_0_0>(invoking:) ()
#38 0x00000001a9cd72b8 in closure #1 in static NSRunLoop.addObserver(_:) ()
#39 0x00000001a9cd7410 in @objc closure #1 in static NSRunLoop.addObserver(_:) ()
#40 0x00000001a3437588 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#41 0x00000001a34316ac in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#42 0x00000001a3431c58 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#43 0x00000001a3431308 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#44 0x00000001baab4734 in GSEventRunModal ()
#45 0x00000001a5eaf75c in -[UIApplication _run] ()
#46 0x00000001a5eb4fcc in UIApplicationMain ()
#47 0x00000001aa39c380 in closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) ()
#48 0x00000001aa39c30c in runApp<τ_0_0>(_:) ()
#49 0x00000001a9e94b38 in static App.main() ()
#50 0x000000010031c9c4 in static SwiftUIForEachTestApp.$main() at /xxx/SwiftUIForEachTest/Shared/ContentView.swift:16
#51 0x000000010031e888 in main ()
#52 0x00000001a30edcf8 in start ()
```

Is this a bug in SwiftUI?

Comment: Note: MyView should be a struct

Answer (score 0):

works very well for me on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15 and macCatalyst.
Tested on mac, iPhone and iPad. Maybe it is different on older systems.

EDIT: using EnvironmentObject, this is the code I'm using in my tests:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject var model = MyModel()  // <--- 
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(model)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MyModel // <---
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MyView()
        }
    }
}
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: MyModel  // <---
    @State private var isPresentingSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach($model.vegetables) { $vegetable in
                Text(vegetable.name)
            }
            .onDelete { indices in model.vegetables.remove(atOffsets: indices) }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresentingSheet) {
            Text("the sheet")  // <----
        }
    }
}
struct Vegetable: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
}

class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var vegetables: [Vegetable] = [
        Vegetable(id: UUID(), name: "Eggplant"),
        Vegetable(id: UUID(), name: "Corn"),
        Vegetable(id: UUID(), name: "Radish")
    ]
}
```

Comment: hard to believe it would make a different, but then again.

Comment: just updated an hour ago to xcode 13.0-beta5

Comment: I still had xcode 13.0-beta4, works just as well with that xcode.

Comment: Your answer helped me uncover the real issue. Please see my edited question for details.

Comment: your new code still works well for me. See my answer EDIT for the minor changes I made. On which line does your code crash?

Comment: Thanks again for testing. Hopefully someone else with iOS 14 will give it a try for another data point.

Comment: all works very well on my older iPad with ios 14.7.1. Are you really using just the code that you are showing, or do you have "other" code as well as the one you show?

Comment: The code I posted is all I'm using to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added the crash log. The debugger breaks at the line `@main` as soon as I delete the top item.

Comment: cannot see what the reason for the crash is. I've updated the code in my answer, of significance maybe, is I added `@EnvironmentObject var model: MyModel` to the "ContentView". Could you try this code exactly as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235974/discussion-between-sbooth-and-workingdog).